# Starting VBS script from python code with minimized window?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, vbscript

I have vbs script which i want to run from python code, on Windows 10, but with minimized window, so that the window does not appear on the screen in an expanded form.
I tried to use subprocesses.Popen with startup info argument like:

```
SW_MINIMIZE = 6 
# I also tried SW_HIDE = 0
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE
subprocess.Popen(["C:/Windows/SysWOW64/cscript.exe", "script.vbs"], startupinfo=info)
```

but i didn't get the expected result - script window still pops up when i run python script.

I also tried to call it with cmd command `"start /min script.vbs"` - also unsuccessfuly.

Is it possible to start the window initially minimized? or at least minimize the window immediately after start without waiting

Comment: Try using the constant `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2` instead.

Comment: i've tried but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using PyQt5, this is not exactly what i was looking for, but it works

```
class MainForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def init_ui(self):
        proc = QProcess()
        command = "C:/Windows/SysWOW64/wscript.exe"
        proc.setProgram(command)
        args = ['C:/work/script.vbs',]
        proc.setArguments(args)
        proc.start()
        
        window_title = 'title'
        # you need to know title of your external app window
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(
             0, 0, None, windows_title)
    
        container = self.createWindowContainer(window, self)
        layout.addWidget(container)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 450, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle(window_title)
        self.showMinimized()
        # or self.show() if you need pop up window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mf = MainForm()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using wscript.exe instead of cscript. Depending on your vbs script this should not show ANY script window at all.

If you need a minimized window you could modify the code found in [this solution](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-start-a-script-in-a-hidden-window/) and start your script like this:

```
Const MIN_WINDOW = 2

strComputer = “.”

Set objWMIService = GetObject(“winmgmts:\\” & strComputer & “\root\cimv2”)

Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get(“Win32_ProcessStartup”)
Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = MIN_WINDOW

Set objProcess = GetObject(“winmgmts:\\” & strComputer & “\root\cimv2:Win32_Process”)

objProcess.Create “Cscript.exe C:\Scripts\Test.vbs”, null, objConfig, intProcessID
```

Comment: wscript.exe - give the same result.
Regard the second suggestion, if i correct - i should copy this to my vbs and modify line with script name? However i've tried to do this, and also creating separate script. But with this content i get compile error. 
unfortunately never had any business before with vbs